# Array.from in javascript not working when requiring JavaScript Collections.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, collectionsjs

I'm trying to learn to use Array.from, as I really don't like calling fill and then map

For example I'm converting

```
const tasks = 3
const graph = Array(tasks).fill(0).map(() => Array())
```

into

```
const graph = Array.from(Array(tasks), () => new Array())
```

but I get the following error

```
graph[1].push(1)
        ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
```

I saw on another thread someone post

```
var arr = Array.from(Array(2), () => new Array(4));
arr[0][0] = 'foo';
console.info(arr);
```

And this too throws

```
arr[0][0] = 'foo';
          ^
TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined
```

After testing line by line, it appears this line breaks it

```
const Deque = require('collections/deque')
```

Any ideas why https://www.collectionsjs.com breaks the array.from() behavior?

Comment: @Pointy it's a simple integer, added above for reference

Comment: Right, well I can't reproduce the problem, `Array.from(Array(tasks), () => new Array())` creates an array of arrays correctly.

Comment: @Pointy were you able to then perform a push or set a value as above?  I see that I get an array of length equal to "tasks" but the items are undefined

Comment: Yes, your code worked fine. You can try it yourself in your developer console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated, my code itself *should* work, however something in collections.js breaks array.from()

Answer (score 0):

As people are saying in the comments, your code works. I'm only adding it as an answer to include this code snippet so that you can see for yourself.

I imagine the problem  is to do with where you're calling `graph[1].push(1)`. I suspect it's being called from somewhere that doesn't have access to `graph`.

The minimal version presented below works, so you need to find the minimal version of your code that causes the error, and you'll probably find the answer in the process

```js
const tasks = 3
const graph = Array.from(Array(tasks), () => new Array())
graph[1].push(1);
console.log(graph)
```

Comment: Okay, so at least I'm not crazy, I found that what's breaking it for some reason is this line: "const Deque = require('collections/deque')" any idea why this breaks the array.from() behavior?